# Origin of the lakshmi mantra

Tags: mantras

Can someone share the origin of this mantra? where was it mentioned? or is it something made up?

Om Shreeng Hreeng Shreeng Kamaley Kamalalaye Praseed Praseed

The second part some have it as

Shreeng Hreeng Shreeng **Om** Mahalaxmyai Namah

and some has Om at the beginning

**Om** Shreeng Hreeng Shreeng Mahalaxmyai Namah

Comment: This mantra is used as what is called a सम्पुट् while reading the Sri Suktam. It is known as Lakshmi Mula Mantra.